# Iterator loop with multiple conditions in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator, conditional-statements

So I'm aware that you can create a for loop with several conditions:

```
for (int i=0; i<5&&i%2!=1; i++){
//Do something
}
```

Can the same thing be done in a iterator loop, if so, could an example be given:

```
String[] arrayofstrings = {"Hello", "World"};
for (String s : arrayofstrings){
//Do something
}
```

Comment: You can't. Use appropriate `break`s inside the `enhanced for` if you absolutely intend to use it. There's no apparent advantage using it in this case, though, so use the `traditional for` for such needs.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of would be to filter the collection before looping over it.  But that's quite different.

Comment: It may be more efficient to extend [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and overload the hasNext() and next() functions with your checks, than to filter out items prior to looping through it. The other benefit of this method is clarity, but I believe this requires using a [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) interface to iterate through. I can write up a quick example as an answer if this is relevant to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't add conditions in the `foreach` loop. It can only be used to iterate through the elements.

It can only be like:

```
for (String s : arrayofstrings){
//Do something
}
```

and it can't be like:

```
for (String s : arrayofstrings && some condition){
//Do something
}
```

Comment: What would be the best way to go abouts this though?

Answer (score 0):

Uh, your question is very unclear here.

The first example is a forloop, where the middle section with the conditions is the condition that checks when to stop. Basically, you can think of it as a while loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5 && i != 3; i++) {
    doSomething();
}
```

is the same as

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 5 && i != 3) {
    doSomething();
    i++;
}
```

The second one just iterates through the items in your list. There is no sort of condition...

```
String[] arrayofstrings = {"Hello", "World"};
for(String s : arrayofstrings) {
    System.out.prinltn(s);
}
```

Will print out

> Hello
>
> World

What sort of condition would you want here. It is basically the equivalent of doing

```
String[] arrayofstrings = {"Hello", "World"};
for(int i = 0; i < arrayofstrings.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arrayofstrings[i]);
}
```

There is no condition being evaluated or a time to stop...

Comment: Thanks I didn't need such a detailed answer. I think the question was fairly clear.